# CSS Vertical Alignment of containers

Tags: css, alignment

I am trying to align my containers vertically.

Basically the top container is a few pixels to the right of the container. I have tried a few things but have not had any success. Does anyone have any expertise ?

Below is my CSS

```
/* structure */
.container {
    background: #FFF;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px 10px ;
    width: 780px;
    transform: translateY(2.5%);
    Clear:Left ;
}

/* header */
.top {
    background: url(img/clouds.gif) repeat-x;
    padding: 50px 10px 0;
}

/* title */
.header {
    background: #FFF;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px;
    width: 780px;
}

.header .left, .header .right {
    background: #A4A4A0;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 150px;  
}

.header .left {
    background: #B3C2C7 url(img/header.jpg) no-repeat;
    font: normal 2.8em "Trebuchet MS",sans-serif;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center; 
    width: 564px;
}

.header .right {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 190px;
}

.header .right p,.header .right h2 {padding: 0 16px;}
.header .right h2 {padding-top: 16px; font: normal 1.6em "Trebuchet MS",sans-serif;}

/* main */
.main {
    border-top: 4px solid #FFF;
    background: url(img/bgmain.gif) repeat-y;
}
```

```css
.left {float: left;}

.right {float: right;}

/* structure */
.container {
 background: #F0F0;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 10px 10px ;
 width: 780px;
 transform: translateY(2.5%);
 Clear:Left ;
   
}

/* header */
.top {
 
 padding: 50px 10px 0;
 
}

/* title */
.header {
 background: #F1F1;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 height: 170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px 10px 5px;
 width: 780px;
 
 
}
.header .left, .header .right {
 background: #A4A4A0;
 color: #FFF;
 height: 150px; 
 
}
.header .left {
 
 font: normal 2.8em "Trebuchet MS",sans-serif;
 line-height: 150px;
 text-align: center; 
 width: 564px;
}
.header .right {
 overflow: auto;
 width: 190px;
}
.header .right p,.header .right h2 {padding: 0 16px;}
.header .right h2 {padding-top: 16px; font: normal 1.6em "Trebuchet MS",sans-serif;}


/* main */
.main {
 border-top: 4px solid #FFF;
    background: #A4A4A0; 
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="top">
    
 <div class="header">

  <div class="left">
   xxx 
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">

   <h2>xx</h2>
   <p>xxx</p>

  </div>

  
  
  <div> 

</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container"> 

          
 <div class="main">  
        <p>Hello</p>
            
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle, include HTML too.

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align`?

Comment: yes I have tried vertical-align

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align:middle;` works fine after `display:table-cell;`